# EF CodeFirst Linq Query Many to many

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two classes that form a many to many relationship.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}
```

I need to select all the products which are contain in certain category. For example all the product in category with ID equal to 1, Or all the products in the categories with ID 1 and 3. 
How can I write this query in Linq?

Note: 
I want Use this as filtering technique. I have this code:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GVProducts_GetData(string Sort)
        {
            var query = _db.Products.AsQueryable();

            //Here I want filter my data 
            if (Sort == "1")
            {
                query = (here should select all the product which are in category 1)
            }
            else if (Sort == "2")
            {
                query = (here should select all the product which are in category 2)
            }
        return query;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create method:

```
  public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(params int[] selectCategory )
   {               
     return repository.Query<Category>       
    (p => selectCategory.Contains(p.ID)).SelectMany(p => p.Products).ToList()

   }
```

example of use:

```
var product = GetProducts(1,3,5);
```

where 1,3,5 sought category

Answer (score 2):

```
     DbContext.Category.Where(c => c.ID == 1)
      .Include(c => c.Products).Select(x => x.Products).ToList();
```

Could be something like this. Make sure to use Include.

Comment: please check the note